Adding members to team throws Generic Sql error
In Dynamics v9 on-prem I'm trying to add members to the team using the following code snippet:
public static void AddMembersToTeam(Guid teamId, Guid[] membersId, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        AddMembersTeamRequest addRequest = new AddMembersTeamRequest();
    
        addRequest.TeamId = teamId;
    
        addRequest.MemberIds = membersId;
    
        service.Execute(addRequest);
    }

I receive an error:

Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Generic SQL error. --->
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Generic SQL error. --->
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted
with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "system_user_team_membership". The
conflict occurred in database "rs_MSCRM", table "dbo.SystemUserBase",
column 'SystemUserId'. The statement has been terminated.    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteWithRetry[TResult](Func1
ExecuteMethod, IDbCommand command)    at
Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.<>c__DisplayClass106_0.b__0()
at
Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger
logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func1 func)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func1 func)    at
Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Server.DataEngine.SqlDataAccessManager.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
at
Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger
logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func1 func)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func1 func)    at
Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Server.DataEngine.EntityCrudManager.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
at
Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger
logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action)  
at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger
logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)    at
Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity
entity, ExecutionContext context)    at
Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.CreateAssociation(BusinessEntityMoniker
entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker,
ManyToManyEntityRelationship manyToManyRelationship, Relationship
entityOneRelationship, Relationship entityTwoRelationship, Guid
primaryKeyValue, ExecutionContext context)    at
Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.CreateAssociation(BusinessEntityMoniker
entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String
associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)    at
Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TeamMembershipServiceInternal`1.Associate(BusinessEntityMoniker
entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String
associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)    at
Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.HandleAssociationOperation(BusinessEntityMoniker
entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String
associationRelationshipName, Boolean createAssociation,
ExecutionContext context)    at
Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.AssociateEntities(BusinessEntityMoniker
entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String
associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)    --- End of
inner exception stack trace ---    --- End of inner exception stack
trace ---    at
Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext
context)    at
Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean
instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName,
ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context)  
at
Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.b__0()

What's wrong ? This code executes successfully in different on-prem organization and cloud as well.

The error is pointing to one of your members that you're trying to add already being a member on the team.  You'll could check for membership first before adding, or add members one at a time, ignoring the ones that fall with the given error.

It was my mistake, I was passing different record id's which didn't belong to user.
